# Can't load java applets using html

Tags: java

I'm newbie with java-applets I'm trying to load it in the web-browser, My class simply look like:

```
 public class AppletWebBrowser extends JApplet {

    public AppletWebBrowser(){
        add(new JLabel("Hi From web"), JLabel.CENTER);
    }
  }
```

And My HTML look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Passing string to Java applet </title>
</head>
<body>
<p> This applet get message from the HTML page and displays it.</p>

<applet
        code = "AppletWebBrowser.class"
        width = 250
        height = 50
        alt = "You must have a Java enabled browser to view the applet">
        <param name = MESSAGE value = "Welcome to Java"/>
        <param name = X value = 20"/>
        <param name = Y value = 30"/>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

The `File.html` and `AppletWebBrowser.java` are in the same folder.

My problem when I open my `file.html` it doesn't load the `AppletWebBrowser.class`

It just display this:

[image]

I'm using chrome.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using applets is in this day and age though. It's a horribly obsolete technology

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I'm on my way to learn it, so please provide the alternative.

Comment: HTML5 and JavaScript can get you a long way, and there's plenty of stuff supported by modern browsers to equal or exceed what applets can do (canvas, webgl, etcetera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

> Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)
>
> The Java plug-in for web browsers relies on the cross platform plugin
>   architecture NPAPI, which has been supported by all major web browsers
>   for over a decade. Google's Chrome version 45 (scheduled for release
>   in September 2015) drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for
>   Silverlight, Java, Facebook Video and other similar NPAPI based
>   plugins.
>
> Java applications are offered through web browsers as either a web
>   start application (which do not interact with the browser once they
>   are launched) or as a Java applet (which might interact with the
>   browser). This change does not affect Web Start applications, it only
>   impacts applets.
>
> If you have problems accessing Java applications using Chrome, Oracle
>   recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X)
>   instead.
>
> Developers and System administrators looking for alternative ways to
>   support users of Chrome should see this blog regarding Launching Web
>   Start applications.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any alternative way cover a wide rang of web-browser?

Comment: @user10548941 At the bottom of the page that I linked, there's another link to a technology called webstart, it's probably your best bet at this stage, as applets are just no longer a good solution (they probably never were really, but at least they used to be supported). Anyway, webstart will allow you to deliver the applet as a Java application instead (it doesn't allow you to embed it in a webpage or whatever, but it's the best you can achieve)

Comment: @user10548941 If you want to embed stuff directly in the browswer, you should take a look at the HTML5 canvas.